# How to allow serviceworkers for http in chrome

Tags: service-worker

Currently I am testing my **ServiceWorker** in my localhost only.
But the problem is, if i change 'localhost' to my machine name in the url, it does not allow **ServiceWorker** and serves the vanilla response.I assume it's because serviceworker is not allowed for http.

Now, if I want to send some one a testlink with my machinename , i am not able to do that.I want to know if there is any way to allow serviceworker for chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Options for testing service workers via HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160509/options-for-testing-service-workers-via-http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to send a link to other people, you need to expose your server through https to the public Internet. You could [set an https server with an autosigned certificate up](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server) but I think the simplest option is to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Once you have ngrok installed, launch a local server as:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

And then launch ngrok with:

```
$ ngrok http 8000
```

Given `8000` is the port where the Python server started, you will see:

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                     (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0.19/2.0.20
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://27223554.ngrok.io -> localhost:8000
Forwarding                    https://27223554.ngrok.io -> localhost:8000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Now distribute `https://27223554.ngrok.io` as the link for testing your site. It will work as you keep ngrok running and connected to the Internet. Of course, you can use the link yourself as well.

Comment: Although ngrok is a cool tool I run some tests and could not make my service worker register.

Comment: Weird, I use it on daily basis and it works for me. Can you point me to a specific error?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is duplicate because this is much more especific.

I run some tests and my advice is you should use Firefox with devtools.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled for your clients

- If you only use ngrok that won't help you (although is an amazing tool)
- If you want to use --unsafety-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure you should know that you can't use it for chrome, it is unsupported. Maybe canary or chronium works but i didn't checked.