# Flutter WebRTC: GetUserMedia() does not work for Safari and IOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, webrtc

I am currently developing an app using the **flutter_webrtc** package. It turns out that when I call WebRTC's getUserMedia method as blow, it does not prompt me to check for camera permission, and the whole app is just stuck. This situation happens with Mac Safari and both IOS Chrome and Safari.

```
var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
_localStream = stream;
_localRenderer.srcObject = _localStream;
stream.getTracks().forEach((element) {
  _peerConnection!.addTrack(element, stream); 
});
```

This code is directly from the official flutter_webrtc sample: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/main/example/lib/src/get_user_media_sample.dart. The version of my flutter_webrtc package is 0.9.47, the version for my Mac safari is 17.3, the version for my Dart SDK is 3.2.3, and the version for my Flutter is 3.16.5.

In addition, I've found out the following code snippet from the compiled Javascript file `main.dart.js`. It seems that Flutter calls a specific method called `webkitGetUserMedia` which seems to fit into Safari, but it just doesn't work. Probably due to some restrictions by Apple?

```
A.zu.prototype = {
        WO(a, b, c) {
            var s = new A.ay($.ah, t.xN),
                r = new A.bF(s, t.Rt),
                q = A.ar(["audio", b, "video", c], t.N, t.z),
                p = !a.getUserMedia
            p.toString
            if (p)
                a.getUserMedia = a.getUserMedia || a.webkitGetUserMedia || a.mozGetUserMedia || a.msGetUserMedia
            this.a51(a, new A.W_([], []).li(q), new A.a86(r), new A.a87(r))
            return s
        },
        a51(a, b, c, d) {
            return a.getUserMedia(b, A.ji(c, 1), A.ji(d, 1))
        }
}
```

I greatly appreciate anyone who knows the solution to this problem so that getUserMedia can work for Flutter Web App for IOS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running without HTTPS. `getUserMedia` API is supported only over secure origins (HTTPS). You can either deploy your code to a secure origin or disable the secure origin policy for Testing purpose only in Chrome by navigating to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`. For more information:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
2. [How to access Camera and Microphone in Chrome without HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759992/how-to-access-camera-and-microphone-in-chrome-without-https)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have deployed my web app to Firebase hosting, which is a secure origin, I guess. Firefox and Chrome work greatly for me, but when I use Safari on Mac, it doesn't work. I guess it's a problem with Safari?

Comment: Currently, I don't have a Mac with me, I will borrow my brother's Mac and attempt to run it by cloning example code from the official repository. I will let you know once it's done. Also, if you don't mind, could you please share the URL where you deployed the WebRTC app?

Comment: Oh my god, thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. The app is on internal testing now so I can't really share... Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah I've found the solution, it's not because of `GetUserMedia()`, but because of the WebRTC policy of Safari. Safari requires `Member RTCIceServer.urls` for ICE servers, but I use RTCIceServer.url.

Comment: Glad you found the solution!