# Why Lighthouse PWA score is blank even though the page is audited

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I'm using chrome 80 DevTools for auditing my page using Lighthouse. Lighthouse audit works fine for Performance, Accessibility, Best Practices, and SEO. However, for PWA even though I see the audit description there is no score, the score field(the circle) is grayed out(like an inactive HTML element). I was doing the [google codelab for PWA](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-offline-quickstart/index.html?index=..%2F..dev-pwa-training#3). I don't believe the issue is the code, if that was so the audit would have given some score at least 0 score. I tried disabling chrome extensions and also ran the audit in incognito mode but there is no difference.

[image]

The audit description and the run-time settings look like the following:

[image]

Comment: that's were I tried it.

Comment: Please provide more information, from developers console, from STDERR (start Chrome using the terminal), also please show your response mime type and status code.

Comment: I have added some more info

Answer (score 4):

According to exterkamp from this [lighthouse github issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/7253): "The PWA section was refactored, so it no longers displays the audit score. This is now the new normal for the PWA section audit of lighthouse. The PWA Audit displaying a gray dash like the image below is not a bug but a feature."

I also took the Google CodeLabs and I noticed that once I completed the step of adding the web app icon to the homescreen, the gray dash was gone and it was replaced with
[PWA Icon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hjyn.png)

exterkamp from the github issue says: The PWA section still has a numeric score underlying it and can be seen if you run the CLI tool and generate JSON reports, or download the devtools report and look at the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

PWA require HTTPS to work.

You are using unencrypted HTTP protocol.

Using Chrome, there are exceptions to be added if you want working pwa over http in your local network:

["unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure" flag is not working on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696280/unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure-flag-is-not-working-on-chrome/53388534#53388534)

Comment: I'm using local server, and I did a step by step procedure on a google training document. According to the document this is not the expected result for my tests.

Comment: besides that, the audit has already taken place because I see a detailed description. The only problem is the score field.

Comment: @Addis please share the information not present in the question

Comment: Ok I will in a minute

Comment: @Addis I think the score is not displayed because you have errors, like the manifest and the start_url. The PWA doesn't seem to be registered correctly. Keep in mind: Google is not perfect and the tutorial you are working is about a year old and things have changed in the meantime.

Comment: I have confirmed that the PWA is registered, installed and activated, the fetch events are also working fine. I have been able to see all the event cycles on the console, the app also works offline. I agree, though, that there could be errors in the tutorial but I feel like the error could be in Lighthouse itself if not mine.

Comment: @Addis I agree, could be totally a bug in Lighthouse. I'd open an issue on github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues

Comment: Thanks! That's what I think too. How would I be able to follow the issue?

Comment: @Addis You will get notified by github when there are responses to a created issue :-) Good luck solving this problem!

Comment: Thanks for the help!