# cordova works fine on local but not on remote host

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, progressive-web-apps

```
function Talk()
{
    var vis = $('#MyWrapper').css("visibility");

    if(vis == "visible")
    {
        $('#MyWrapper').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
    }
    else if(vis == "hidden")
    {
        $('#MyiWrapper').css({ visibility: "visible" });
    }
}


function onDeviceReady() 
{    
    $('#myButton').click(Talk);
}
```

I have a cordova app containing the above code in its www/scripts/index.js file. My app is working fine on local visual studio testing with Ripple emulator but when it is uploaded pressing the defined button doesn't have any effect. Why is that. How can I debug an uploaded progressive web app with browser. I am new to cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa#recommendation), for PWAs, you can cache static resources, composing your application shell (JS/CSS/HTML files) using the Cache API and fill in the offline page data from IndexedDB. Debugging support for IndexedDB is now available in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/manage-data/local-storage) (Application tab), Opera, [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) (Storage Inspector) and Safari (Storage tab).

Also from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34161385/5832311), if you need to test things on a remote web server that doesn't support HTTPS, there is a manual workaround you can use. It involves starting up Chrome via the command line, and using both the `--user-data-dir` and `--unsafety-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` flags.

Hope this helps!