# Vue.js PWA, vuex: 'An unknown error occured when fetching the script'

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, vuex, offline-caching, progressive-web-apps

I have the following setup:

1. Vue PWA starter
2. Vuex store
3. [Persist plugin](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist) to have data available offline

The sw registers properly and also loads the cached files containing my vue app when offline. The problem: The data that's stored in the localStorage doesn't show up, although it is available in the localStorage.

In Chrome's `Application` tab I see the error `An unknown error occured when fetching the script`. There's no assigned line of code from the worker or anything else.

So right now I don't know whether the problem is my worker, the plugin or something else. Are there any good approaches to tackle such 'magic' problems?

BTW: I left the service worker as is from the Vue PWA starter.

Store initialisation if it helps:

```
const localStorageConfig = new VuexPersistence({
  key: 'someAppCode',
});

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user,
    client,
    tours,
  },
  plugins: [localStorageConfig.plugin],
});
```

Comment: Are you using https? If not, that might be the problem.

Comment: @BillCriswell No I don't --> is there any way to use "Web Server for Chrome" with https?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. This might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160509/options-for-testing-service-workers-via-http

Comment: It looks like if you're using `localhost` with a port it should still work. Are you testing with a fake domain name or something like that?

Comment: I accessed via `127.0.0.1`, now changed to simpleHttp again and accessing via localhost. The problem is still the same.

Comment: Update: I'm quite sure it's a problem with the vuex plugin. I now use a plain-vue plugin, which works perfectly fine.