# TROUBLE with cerf for making HTTPS from ssl in localhost

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, service-worker

Hello currently i am in project making progressive-web app using my local webserver-express. Im totally in my confusion after so many days no progress.

because I need to use PWA in my phone then I really need to enable https for service-worker.

I have tried using self-signed cerf, it doesnt work for the service worker and there is a way to enable [http with service-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160509/options-for-testing-service-workers-via-http/34161385#34161385) but it only accessible in PC-chrome while i really need the service-worker works in my android or smartphone not in my PC-only.

so I just bought the real cerf to attain **HTTPS** and i am little bit confused because im still unfamiliar with domain etc.

I follow [this guide](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-a-csr-for-https-tls-ssl-rsa-pems/) JUST bought my ssl and a new domain cause i run my PWA in my local webserver.

but my domain is still new so it's still locked for 60days, I don't know if i buy in another site it will be locked or not and will have to buy a new ssl again.

I got 4 cerf :

1. my domain cerf
2. Root cerf
3. Intermediate cerf
4. Webserver cerf

so i try to run my webserver express in my local ip+port with these 4 cerfs and so here the questions because i have little knowledge :

1. My domain cerf and intermediate shouldnt be work because my domain is still locked right ?
2. My root cerf doesnt work either in my local-webserver even tho i have imported the cerf in chrome. ( the https is still red, i could access the my site but i don't need red https because the service worker need green-https (?) )
3. I don't know what to do with webserver-cerf , well I did applied it in my code, it do nothing either.

   ```
   options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certsPath, 'my-server.key.pem'))

     , ca: [
       fs.readFileSync(path.join(caCertsPath, 'webserver.crt.pem'))

     ,fs.readFileSync(path.join(caCertsPath, 'intermediate.crt.pem'))
           ,fs.readFileSync(path.join(caCertsPath, 'my-root-
      ca.crt.pem'))
             ]

   , cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certsPath, 'my-server.crt.pem'))

   , requestCert: false
   , rejectUnauthorized: true
   };
   ```

later :

```
https.createServer(options, app);
```

I assumed you guys know how this works right ? nodejs.express

I don't really think the code for webserver is the problem but more like the cert-understanding, domain-world and how local-webserver works with https. 
The more i research the more i confused now.

I run https://ip:port  none of the working with my https-cerf.

basicly i just need to make  **green HTTPS** in my local webserver, but how ? I did bought the cerf and it doesnt work, so before i bought another i have to make sure what kind of problem i have right now ?

another question: my domain is unlocked but there is nameserver while i dont have host-provider, could i use my local-ip to the nameserver ? im seriously confused how this things work now. I don't even know what is the thing i confused right now, don't know what to ask.

sorry for bad grammar, but i would like if you guys correct mine.

EDIT : mistaken unlocked and locked

Answer (score 0):

Service workers normally require `https:`, but `localhost` is the exception. Any `http://localhost:<port>` origins will work with service workers.

Since you mention needing to test things on your phone, and assuming it's an Android device and you're using Chrome, the information in the "[Access Local Servers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server)" guide should help you.

You can run a local web server and then use Chrome to forward the port to an Android device connected via a USB cable, and the Android device can load your content and take full advantage of service workers via the same `http://localhost:<port>` origin.