# Chrome DevTools > Service Workers > Testing > Local dev environment serves via http on a LAN

Tags: testing, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment, service-worker

As above, is there an easy way to allow service workers for local development when served via http on a local network when using chrome & dev tools?

Is there a port # to serve on? Did I miss an option in Dev Tools to allow a domain?

I am aware of this [answer from a Google Dev suggesting it isn't possible without hacking chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34161385/4806086), but that answer was given back in 2015 and a lot has happened with PWA/sw.js since then - so I am hoping I'll get lucky!

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way is to install [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en) Extension and select the *work* folder inside the App and start web server in seconds to test Service Worker.

Comment: Thanks for trying (+1). This would work where dev output urls are relative, but mine are absolute urls with the lan address hard coded - so I'd only get  access to  root the index.html. It would be easier for me to set dev output to serve on localhost - which I am thinking I will just do.

Answer (score 0):

No change. For service workers to work, the LAN needs a valid SSL certificate.

Workarounds appears to be:

1. serve dev on localhost, if you can;
2. as per the link in my question, launch chrome from terminal with unsafe flags and temporary directory (also see [this hopefully available link showing an example command](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/EYqASMdFEI0)); or
3. if your dev build output has relative uris, launch another server on your computer (e.g. web server for chrome) with the relevant LAN dir as source.

I simply went localhost.

If a Chrome Dev sees this, it might be a handy feature to add an option in DevTools > Application to temporarily permit an unsafe domain (like the flags option).

Have fun people.