# PWA: Getting Web Share API to work in development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, progressive-web-apps

Since Google Chrome and Firefox [does not support Web Share yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#Browser_compatibility), I need some alternative way to test this in development.

Sharing is achieved via [this example](https://web.dev/web-share/):

```
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    title: 'web.dev',
    text: 'Check out web.dev.',
    url: 'https://web.dev/',
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
} else {
  console.warn('Cannot share in this browser')
}
```

Which will log for any unsupported browser:

```
Cannot share in this browser
```

Any ideas of how to get this to work for development?

Answer (score 1):

It seems [using Chrome Dev Tools to forward the local port to a remote device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43426714) is the best way to debug on mobile devices and thus test PWA functionality on a device itself.

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost` is [considered a secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) … or you could just set up HTTPS in your local development environment.

Comment: I've added more context to the question

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop browsers do not [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#Browser_compatibility) the Web Share API. Currently Chrome is one that does not.

Comment: So how does one test this in development do you think?

Comment: Android emulator would probably work. Or a tool like ngrok so you can load the dev site on your phone.