# Subject Alternative Names for Localhost

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subject-alternative-name

I am trying to connect to localhost over https so that I can use service workers. I have tried many solutions such as chrome flags as described in posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160509/options-for-testing-service-workers-via-http), but none have worked. Finally, I used OpenSSL to make myself a certificate authority and sign my own certificate. However, despite everything running correctly Chrome (and other browsers) still rejected my certificate.

This was due to the lack of subject alternative names. I then added my IP address as an alternate name, but it was not accepted either - chrome told me that the "domain came from [IP address]", along with the error message `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`
What other subject alternative names can I use to prove my identity over localhost? (or alternatively, are there any other solutions?) I am using Apache with XAMPP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SAN must match the domain in the URL you use. If you use `https://localhost` then there must be a SAN of type DNS with value `localhost`. If you use `https://127.0.0.1` then there must be a SAN of type IP with value `127.0.0.1`. Not the importance of the correct type and not only of the value.

> I use localhost as the common name. From my understanding the SAN must be different but still refer to the same domain ...

No. The CN is actually irrelevant and will usually not even be looked at if a SAN is given (or in case of Chrome: it will never look at the CN and requires always SAN). So just make sure that the SAN is correct.

Comment: I use `localhost` as the common name. From my understanding the SAN must be different but still refer to the same domain, hence why I used my IP address. Should I instead set the SAN to `https://localhost` as well?

Comment: @Toby: your understanding is wrong, see updated answer.

Comment: I have the SAN set to https://localhost, yet still get the same error message `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`, along with the message "This server could not prove that it is **localhost**; its security certificate is from **localhost**". I realize that I may now have a different problem than I realized, if Chrome doesn't simply accept by SAN. Do you have any other ideas? Or I will make a new post.

Comment: @Toby: I'm not sure what you are really doing, please provide the __exact__ certificate and __exact__ URL you are using? Note that the SAN should not be `https://localhost` but just `localhost`.

Comment: Changing the SAN to just `localhost` worked. Thank you so much, this has taken a lot of time.

Comment: Any names for WLAN network? Like wifi or hotspot? Same as LocalHost? Plz help anyone?