# Cannot setup service worker with self-signed cert and webpack dev server

Tags: ssl, webpack, service-worker

I'm new to Progressive Web Apps, and I'm adding a Service Worker to my app for the very first time. It's a simple Service Worker, with my goal being purely to test that it is being registered properly. The file is serviceWorker.js:

```
console.log('Hello Service Worker');
```

I'm adding this to an application that I'm running with the Webpack Dev Server. I'm using a self-signed certificate locally with it. I setup the Service Worker in my index.tsx (React Typescript) like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('Worker registered'))
        .catch((ex) => console.error('Worker registration error', ex));
}
```

However, when I start the dev server and go to the app, I get an error:

```
Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:3000/') with script ('https://localhost:3000/service-worker.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
```

The URL, `https://localhost:3000/service-worker.js`, does indeed work, the browser is just blocking it because of the self-signed piece of the cert.

I'm using Chrome Browser on on M1 Pro MacBook running MacOS Monterey, with Webpack 5.

For the record, I'm aware of plugins like Workbox, I would prefer not to use them at this time because I'm still very new to Service Workers. I believe in working with the low-level constructs when starting with a new tech to understand them better before embracing easier abstractions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any [features](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features/)—including service workers—that require HTTPS on `localhost`.

`localhost`, and equivalent IP address ranges, are [specifically excluded](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features/#definitions) from HTTPS requirements by Chromium-based browsers, and both Firefox and Safari follow that, at least when it comes to service workers.

So I would suggest that you just access your web site via `http://localhost:3000` instead.

There are more details in this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34161385/385997).