# Implementing Service worker in ionic (capacitor) + vue app

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, service-worker, capacitor

Is it possible to implement service worker for hybrid app (ionic + vue + capacitor). I am getting registration failed error. Thank you! [image]

Comment: Have you tried just adding the localhost port when registering the service worker? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160509/options-for-testing-service-workers-via-http

Comment: I have tried. not working :(